# React-mapbox-gl-draw error on map startup

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl-draw

I just started using `react-mapbox-gl-draw`  in my react-mapbox-gl application. I am following [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-yonath-gm7vo) very quick demo and their [docs](https://github.com/amaurymartiny/react-mapbox-gl-draw) to set up the `<DrawControl />`. Seems pretty simple, but I am running into an issue.

Here's my code, and the error is below:

```
import DrawControl from 'react-mapbox-gl-draw';
import '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/dist/mapbox-gl-draw.css';
// imports 

// ignore the class instantiation, constructor, all that. It works. 

// in the render method: 

<Map
 onStyleLoad={ el => this.map = el} 
 style={this.state.style}
 containerStyle={{
    height: this.state.height,
    width: this.state.width
 }}
 center={[0,0]}
 zoom={[2]} >

     <DrawControl />

</Map>
```

And here is the error:

```
index.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: map.getStyle is not a function
    at DrawControl.componentDidMount (index.js:14)
    at commitLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:14361)
    at commitAllLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:15462)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:100)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:138)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:187)
    at commitRoot (react-dom.development.js:15603)
    at completeRoot (react-dom.development.js:16618)
    at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:16563)
    at performWork (react-dom.development.js:16482)
    at performSyncWork (react-dom.development.js:16454)
    at requestWork (react-dom.development.js:16354)
    at scheduleWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:16218)
    at Object.enqueueSetState (react-dom.development.js:11299)
    at ReactMapboxGl.../../../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js.Component.setState (react.development.js:335)
    at r.<anonymous> (map.js:119)
    at r.Ft.fire (mapbox-gl.js:29)
    at r._render (mapbox-gl.js:33)
    at mapbox-gl.js:33
```

More or less, apparently `<DrawControl />` is trying to call a method as soon as the component (map) mounts, but I'm not sure why or how to fix it. I would appreciate any help and advice!

**-EDIT-**
I added a `MapContext.Consumer` in my map object because it was complaining about wanting a `map` object. So now it is mounting but I cannot see the draw object. Any ideas?

Here's my updated code:

```
<Map
 onStyleLoad={ el => this.map = el} 
 style={this.state.style}
 containerStyle={{
    height: this.state.height,
    width: this.state.width
 }}
 center={[0,0]}
 zoom={[2]} >

    <MapContext.Consumer>
         {(map) => {
              <DrawControl />
         }}
    </MapContext.Consumer>

</Map>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be importing mapbox-gl as well? The deps are listed as   react-mapbox-gl
 mapbox-gl 
@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw
react-mapbox-gl-draw

Comment: @stever Why would I import mapbox-gl? I'm using a react wrapper for it, so I shouldn't be touching any mapbox objects besides passing properties to it. Let me try it though and let you know

Comment: Those are dependencies of mapbox-gl-draw.  

Look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mapbox-gl-draw.  Their example is clear.

Comment: @stever Doesn't work even if I'm importing mapbox-gl. Any other ideas? Plus, I am literally following their example, which didn't work for me haha

Comment: Make sure mapbox-gl is a dependency in your package.json file.

Comment: If not, run `npm install (or yarn add) mapbox-gl`

Comment: @stever I installed all the dependencies for `react-mapbox-gl-draw` and `mapbox-gl` again. Still not working. It might not be an issue of dependencies

Comment: Where is `this.state.style` defined?

Comment: If it's coming from a parent component it's prop not state

Comment: I only got this issue when I added `<DrawControl /> - all my other code works... The state is in my constructor in that class. See my edit for further ideas

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196660/discussion-between-evl-and-stever).

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have the same problem

Comment: @Brad Check my solution out. wrote something quick up for you. let me know if you have more questions

Comment: @evl Thanks, I ended up ditching react-mapbox-gl-draw and using the mapbox-gl-draw API directly and it worked great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was to implement `MapboxDraw` within the `MapContext.Consumer`. Here's a snippet of `MapboxDraw` below and here's the [link](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-draw/) to it. This works because it has access to the map object and can draw directly on the map.

```
var draw = new MapboxDraw({
   displayControlsDefault: false,
   controls: {
   polygon: true,
   trash: true
   }
});
```